# HighStocks/HighCharts scrollbar not displaying with large datasets causing xAxis labels to disappear and making bars not show

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm creating a HighStock column bar chart. I have enabled the scrollbar using scrollbar: enabled. The scrollbar works fine for smaller datasets, but this dataset has a lot of categories(I've only included half as many as I need). For some reason, after a certain number, the rects for the bar chart won't properly show(or show wrong values) and the xAxis labels display as numbers rather than their actual names. Also, I'm trying to add IDs to each of the bars to add click events, but it only adds IDs to bars that are properly rendered initially. I have also noticed that I can properly add IDs even with a scrollbar to smaller data sets because all of the rect elements are properly rendered. Is there any way to make this scrollbar work for larger datasets?

You'll see what the problem described above looks like in this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/sauravvenkat/96ue59qy/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        color: 'rgb(245,111,35)',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Physicians By Specialty'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Physician Specaialty'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },
        // min: 0,
        max: 7,
        tickLength: 0,
        labels: {
            rotation: -60
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Profiles',
            align: 'high'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Totals',
        color: 'rgb(245,111,35)',
        data: [["Spec1",1000],["Spec2", 1000], ["Spec3",500],["Spec4",300],["Spec5",1000],["Spec6", 1000], ["Spec26",500],["Spec27",300],["Spec28",1000],["Spec29", 1000], ["Spec30",500],["Spec31",300],["Spec32",1000],["Spec33", 1000], ["Spec34",500],["Spec35",300],["Spec36",300],["Spec37",300], ["Spec38",300], ["Spec39",300], ["Spec40",300], ["Spec41",300], ["Spec42",300], ["Spec43",300], ["Spec44",300], ["Spec45",300], ["Spec46",300],["Spec47",1000],["Spec48", 1000], ["Spec49",500],["Spec50",300],["Spec51",1000],["Spec52", 1000], ["Spec53",500],["Spec54",300],["Spec55",1000],["Spec56", 1000], ["Spec57",500],["Spec58",300],["Spec59",300],["Spec60",300], ["Spec61",300], ["Spec62",300], ["Spec63",300], ["Spec64",300], ["Spec65",300], ["Spec66",300], ["Spec67",300], ["Spec68",300], ["Spec",300],["Spec24",1000],["Spec25", 1000], ["Spec26",500],["Spec27",300],["Spec28",1000],["Spec29", 1000], ["Spec30",500],["Spec31",300],["Spec32",1000],["Spec33", 1000], ["Spec34",500],["Spec35",300],["Spec36",300], ["Spec44",300], ["Spec45",300], ["Spec46",300],["Unknown",250]]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens because the number of points in series is bigger than the default value of the `cropThreshold` property (more about below, in the API Reference section). As a solution, set the property with the bigger value.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.cropThreshold

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/q8pn2dwf/